# Repeater Item Command not triggered but Causes server side validations on all validators of page

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, user-controls, repeater

I have read similar questions on stack overflow but this might be a bit different. Since the page I am working on has lots of usercontrols and Ajax already working... I will try to summarize the code first

The page has a link button **View Details** that opens a usercontrol **EmploymentOfferDetails** in popup

At the end of this same page, I have added a repeater control with imagebutton and want to open another popup with another user control in it on click of imagebutton

I have added itemcommand to repeater but it is not fired (have read all the repeater item command not firing posts)

Now the problem is when i open click on this imagebutton the employmentOfferDetails control's validator is somehow being triggered and since it has a null object it causes validation false and debugger goes to Application_EndRequest ..Here is the code

(Same code works with an imagebutton outside the repeater control) :S

```
 <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="lbEmploymentOfferDetails">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlEmploymentOfferDetails" LoadingPanelID="rlpRIDESelected" />
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="hfEmploymentOfferId" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="lbEmploymentOfferDummyLink">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlEmploymentOfferDetails" LoadingPanelID="rlpRIDESelected" />
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="hfEmploymentOfferId" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rptMedicareReplyDateGroup">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ucAGPTMailDetails" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="divEmploymentOfferDummylink" style="position:absolute;z-index:900;left:0;top:0;display:none;">
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbEmploymentOfferDummyLink" Text="View Employment Offer Details" Visible="true" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="ShowEmploymentOfferDetails();"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlPlacementBasicInformation">
<div class="control-group required" id="divEmploymentOfferLink" runat="server" visible="false">
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="lbEmploymentOfferDetails" CssClass="control-label"
               Text="Employment Offer" ID="lblEmploymentOffer" />
    <div class="controls">
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbEmploymentOfferDetails" Text="View Details"
                        CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="ShowEmploymentOfferDetails();"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="medicareInformation" class="hide well">
    <!-- Main facility and Additional Sites table -->
    <!--Another repeater control goes here-->

    <div class="control-group">
        <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="lblMedicareReplyDate" Text="Medicare Send Confirmation:"
                   CssClass="control-label" Width="220px" />
        <div class="controls" style="margin-left: 225px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMedicareReplyDate" runat="server" />
            <asp:Literal ID="litMedicareReplyEmaiId" runat="server" Visible="false" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="iBtnMedciareReplyEmail" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/communication-active.png" Width="25px" AlternateText="Click to open email" ToolTip="Click to open email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="rptMedicareReplyDateGroup" Text="Medicare Send Confirmation:"
                   CssClass="control-label" Width="220px" />
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMedicareReplyDateGroup">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row" id="trRepeaterItem" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMedicareReplyDateItem" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Literal ID="litMedicareReplyEmaiIdItem" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="iBtnMedciareReplyEmailItem" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/communication-active.png" CausesValidation="false" Width="25px" AlternateText="Click to open email" ToolTip="Click to open email" CommandName="OpenEmail" OnClientClick="ShowMedicareDetails();" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTest" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowMedicareDetails();" Text="Test Button" OnClick="lnkTest_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</div>
```

on image button click i am opening the modal popup that contains another user control. Now that causes server-side validations of whole page including EmploymentOfferDetails' server side validations and the Application_EndRequest is called because EmploymentOfferDetails is not properly initialized..and therefore (i assume) the repeater itemcommand is not triggered.

The iBtnMedciareReplyEmail(one outside repeater) however works properly.

I hope i am able to explain my issue

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer here:

[Repeater Item Command Causes Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792630/repeater-item-command-causes-validation)

> For anybody that has this problem and stumbles across this post, here's what I found.
>
> Turns out the problem was happening because I had
>   EnableViewState="false" set on the Repeater. This was breaking the
>   event postback somehow, and making every validator on the page fire.
>   All I had to do was manually call DataBind() on the Repeater from
>   within Page_Load(), and it cleared right up.